# Error al intentar instalar "ngx-input-file" en Angular 6

Tags: angular, fileupload, angular6

Intento instalar la librería [***ngx-input-file***](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-input-file).

```
npm install ngx-input-file --save
```

Importo las 2 librerías al ***app.module.ts*** de esta manera:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { InputFileConfig, InputFileModule } from 'ngx-input-file';
```

Agrego **BrowserAnimationsModule** a los **import** y funciona correctamente, pero al agregar **InputFileModule.forRoot(config),** al **import** me arroja el siguiente error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./node_modules/ngx-input-file/fesm5/ngx-input-file.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/button' in 'C:\wamp64\www\webapp\node_modules\ngx-input-file\fesm5'

[image: error]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seguramente lo que te falta es instalar el paquete @angular/material.
Prueba ejecutando esta linea de comandos en el proyecto:

```
npm install --save @angular/material
npm install --save @angular/cdk
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: ahora me arroja este error:

Comment: ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/button/typings/button.d.ts(8,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/a11y'.
node_modules/@angular/material/button/typings/button.d.ts(9,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.
node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/datetime/native-date-adapter.d.ts(8,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.
node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/ripple/ripple-renderer.d.ts(9,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/platform'.

Comment: Entonces ahora podrías instalar esta otra librería:

npm install @angular/cdk

Saludos.

Comment: Listo hermano, eso era. Gracias.

Comment: Edita la respuesta y agrega que también se debe instalar esa librería.